# Command Line - Turn off Password protected sharing

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, cmd

Trying to turn off the Password protected sharing via command line and having no luck at all.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

Password protected sharing  = Off

I have looked at `netsh advfirewall firewall`
And only been able to configure the option for Turn on file and printer sharing.

No registry or command i have seen online can alter this setting, The only placed i have not fully explored is group polices.

PC's come in to be setup, we use a default set of look & feel with a number of settings changed. It would of been nice to have have the one Bat file configure all. But this is the only stumbling block i have hit.

Windows 7 (POS Ready)

I have seen a similar post on here: How do you pro grammatically Turn Password Protected Sharing on/off in Windows 7 
Unfortunately this has not worked for me.

Comment: Enable `Guest` user and allow it to connect from network.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time researching for myself I discovered that as long as you run the command prompt window with admin access the following works:

```
reg add Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters /v restrictnullsessaccess /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

And then you will have to restart your computer (which you can do with `shutdown /r`).

Comment: This did not work for me.  Under Advanced Sharing Settings -> Password Protected Sharing, the radio button is still set to "Turn on password protected sharing", and it still asks for credentials when attempting to browse across the network from a similar computer.   Was there any additional settings you had to do to complete this change?

Comment: Illl check and get back to u

Comment: I'm sorry Mark, I am using Windows 10, I just saw the OP mentioned Windows 7, this may be a valid fix for 7.

Comment: It stopped working for me on Windows 10 but adding `\\` to the beginning fixed it.